# phpunit test class not found error while class is there?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

This is my directory Structure

```
application
---modules
------admin
---------models
-----------User.php
```

This is my user Model class

```
class admin_Model_User 
{
//User.php
}
```

This is my UserTest Class with simple AssertType

```
class admin_Model_UserTest 
    extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testUserModel()
    {

        $testUser = new admin_Model_User();
            $this->assertType("admin_Model_User",$testUser);
    }
}
```

When I run this. I am getting following Errors

```
[tests]# phpunit

PHPUnit 3.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

0
Fatal error: Class 'admin_Model_User' not found in /web/zendbase/tests/application/modules/admin/models/UserTest.php on line 18
```

I know there my must be some path setting. I really could not able to figure out what is really wrong. Looking for help.....

Comment: You included the class file or set up a autoloader?

Comment: yes I defined it in application.ini under production. I don't know if there is any other way of doing this. my application are working fine. it means paths are ok. but when i added the require_once in the Usertest class require_once "/web/zendbase/application/modules/admin/models/User.php"; unit test is running fine. Where should i place autoload code so the phpunit will also load the libraries autmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need to do is this

```
//file:ControllerTestCase.php
<?php
require_once GLOBAL_LIBRARY_PATH. '/Zend/Application.php';
require_once GLOBAL_LIBRARY_PATH. '/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';

abstract class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    protected $_application;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap()
    {
        $this->_application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV,
              APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
        );
        $this->_application->bootstrap();

        /**
         * Fix for ZF-8193
         * http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8193
         * Zend_Controller_Action->getInvokeArg('bootstrap') doesn't work
         * under the unit testing environment.
         */
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        if($front->getParam('bootstrap') === null) {
            $front->setParam('bootstrap', $this->_application->getBootstrap());
        }
    }
}
```

// and then require_once it in Bootstrap file. 
thats all :) it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bootstrap Zend in your project's PHPUnit bootstrap.php file. Even though you are testing models and thus don't need the dispatcher, you must still have `Zend_Application` load `application.ini` and register its autoloader.

You can use `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase` to do the bootstrapping instead and make sure your model tests run after one of these, but that's a bit hacky.

Another option is to `require_once` the model classes manually for each test. The reason this doesn't work automatically via PHPUnit's autoloader is that it doesn't know how to transform the "namespace" `admin_Model` into the path `admin/models`.

Finally, you could write a simple [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to replace the one in PHPUnit. Before converting underscores to slashes, check if the class begins with the "namespace" above and replace it if so.

Comment: I try to impliment autoloader, but it did not even picking the __autoload function. Can you give me some working example please? Through different search on web, I come to know that zend phpunit test does not have in build mechanizm for autoloading. that is really strange.

Comment: @user440771 - PHPUnit has built-in autoloading, and Zend has `Zend_Loader_AutoLoader`, but you'll need to do your own. The page I linked above has many examples for creating complex autoloaders. Post a new question specifically about autoloading (ignore PHPUnit) if you still need to know.